# Showing an Alert Dialog before opening a new activity when Button is Click

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I'm working on my Spinner. When I choose an item and click the SEND button, I want an alert dialog box (with OK button only) to be shown first before opening the New Activity. Seeking for help. Thanks. :')

This is my source code anyway. :')
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.imelda.fortesting;

import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static Button button_send;
    private static Button button_sched;
    ImageView btn_Animate;
    Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.punpColleges));
        spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        OnClickButtonListener();
        OnClickButtonSchedule();
    }


    public void OnClickButtonListener() {

        button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondTesting"));
                        }
                    }
                }

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AlertDialog for this

```
public void OnClickButtonListener() {

    button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button_send.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                       .setTitle("Title")
                                       .setMessage("Message")
                                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
                                 startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }).create().show();
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                       .setTitle("Title")
                                       .setMessage("Message")
                                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondTesting");
                                 startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }).create().show();
                    }
                }
            }

    );
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with "new AlertDialog.Builder(this)." The error is the "this".

Comment: try this new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

Comment: Yes. I've tried that one but the error's still the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

Start the new Activity when the dialog is closed.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("hi")
                    .setMessage("Hello world")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })

                    .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            //open activity
                        }
                    }).create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondTesting"));
                }

              });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onClick` function.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogue.setTitle("Are you sure?");

            alertDialogue.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondTesting"));
                    }

                }
            });

alertDialogue.show();
```

Here you go with your `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.imelda.fortesting;

import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static Button button_send;
    private static Button button_sched;
    ImageView btn_Animate;
    Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.punpColleges));
        spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        OnClickButtonListener();
        OnClickButtonSchedule();
    }


    public void OnClickButtonListener() {

        button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialogue.setTitle("Are you sure?");

                alertDialogue.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CCS")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondTesting"));
                        }

                    }
                });

                alertDialogue.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In what part of the code I should add this? Thanks. :')